# Crazy javascript problem: undefined actually !== undefined!

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Before anyone asks, I have already search existing questions and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined), but the answer was that `undefined` was being set to `null`, which is not the case here.

Here is my code:

```
check_availability = function () {
    var value = $('#contact_type').val();
    if (value !== undefined) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Simple huh? I have a `<select id="contact_type"></select>` with options populated via ajaxy stuff.  Initially the options list is empty, so the jQuery val() returns `undefined`.
So far so good.

Except that the code within the `if` block always executes.  I stick a breakpoint in FireBug on the 3rd line and I get this:

[image: undefined weirdness]

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

P.S. This is Firefox 4.0

---

**EDIT:** I know there are a number of ways I can achieve the same result, I'm more interested in why value is undefined according to FireBug, but then is !== undefined.

Comment: http://juhukinners.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/typeof-considered-useless-or-how-to-write-robust-type-checks/ might be worth reading

Comment: Try this crazy line: `undefined = 7`

Answer (score 3):

Just check the truthiness of `value`.

```
if (value) {
    // sexy times
}
```

BTW, jQuery returns `null`, not `undefined`, when the `<select>` contains no `<option>`s. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cQ83z/

Comment: Ok so the value of val() should actually be null. Is this a bug in FireBug then do you think?

Comment: No, see ThiefMaster's answer: your watch point has `value == undefined` as `true` (which makes sense since `null == undefined`) but `value === undefined` as `false` (which makes sense because `null !== undefined`). If you want to see the actual value, use a proper breakpoint or `console.log(value)`.

Comment: But I also get `undefined` for the watch of just `value`

Comment: As ThiefMaster commented: "Sounds to me like the line assigning something to it wasn't executed yet."

Comment: You can't just check for truthiness if `value` can legally be `0`, as might be the case here.

Comment: @Marcel: `val()` returns a string, not a number, and although the _number_ `0` is falsy, the _string_ `'0'` is truthy. Try it in your console: `!!'0'` prints `true`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `val()` returning a string. However, `"" == false` (if `val()` can return an empty string).

Comment: @Marcel: yes, `val()` can return the empty string. Now _that's_ a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

The `val()` is never `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/UmZhG/

If the `<select>` has no options, it is `null`; otherwise there's always an option selected.

Fyi, `value == undefined` is true since `null == undefined` (even though `null !== undefined`)

Comment: ... did you see the bit where value is undefined in the FireBug screenshot?

Comment: @Stuart: see my answer. jQuery tends to avoid returning `undefined`.

Comment: Sounds to me like the line assigning something to it wasn't executed yet. A `var x` defined in a function will be undefined until its the first assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by it being undefined until its the first assignment?  Isn't it the first assignment?

Comment: Internally no matter where `var x = something;` occurs, every occurence creates `var x;` at the beginning of the function. So the var is defined in the whole function, but only after the first assignment it loses its `undefined` value.

Comment: Ok I knew that, but this doesn't apply in my case, because the var `value` is defined and initialised at the same time (see code).  So what I'm asking is, how can this happen?

Comment: If you stepped right into the function (i.e. the debugger is on the `var x = something` line), the line has not been executed yet. However, the var is already defined (with its value being `undefined`) at this point.

Comment: No, this was after I had stepped past it and the debugger was on the next line!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (typeof(value) != 'undefined') {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was correct but doesn't solve your problem. If I understood, you want to do some action ONLY if there are no `option` tags inside the `select` element, right ? If so, try this: `if ($('#contact_type option').size() > 0) { /* there are options */}`. Also I am assuming you have a a real `<select id="contact_type"></select>` there, instead of what you typed.

Answer (score 1):

the === operator doesn't do type conversions which may causing the error.  try == instead.  or compare against null.

Answer (score 1):

try in this way...

```
if (value != undefined) {
        // do some stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if($("#contact_type").val() != ""){
//does have a value
}else{
//No value there
}
```