# Should I use typeof in Javascript type equality?

Tags: javascript, performance

What is better?

```
if (obj === undefined) { }
```

vs.

```
if (typeof(obj) === 'undefined') { }
```

Comment: The question was related to Performance, and all answers are about the better one regardless of performance

Answer (score 5):

If you somehow can't refrain from shadowing the global `undefined`, or can't keep from trying to reference undeclared variables, then use:

```
typeof x === 'undefined'
```

If you adhere to good coding practices, and believe in letting broken code break, use:

```
x === undefined
```

If you want a different alternative, you can use:

```
x === void 0;
```

...where `void` always returns `undefined`, and doesn't rely on the global property.

Another safeguard you can use is to use shadowing in a good way by defining a proper `undefined` in  a function:

```
(function( undefined ) {

    // notice that no arguments were passed, 
    // so the `undefined` parameter will be `undefined`

    var x; 

    if( x === undefined ) {

    }

})();
```

...some people prefer to give it a different name:

```
(function( undef ) {

    // notice that no arguments were passed, 
    // so the `undefined` parameter will be `undefined`

    var x; 

    if( x === undef ) {

    }

})();
```

Comment: Thorough and accurate, but I'm not sure why you'd consider "letting broken code break" a better coding practice than using something else that is guaranteed to always work and is only slightly more complicated.

Comment: @Tim Down: Well they're personal preferences, but I don't believe in coding to accommodate poor coding practices. Broken code is an excellent instructor. Also, I find the *fix* to be visually hideous and entirely unintuitive. I understand its purpose, but then I think that once a person understands the reasons why they need it, they should no longer need it. Just my opinions. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the second one, as "undefined" is not a reserved word. Example:

```
var obj = undefined;
undefined = {};

if(obj === undefined) {
    console.log("undefined 1");   
}

if(typeof obj === 'undefined') {
    console.log("undefined 2");   
}
```

Will only show "undefined 2" because the variable `undefined` can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked before, but the more common approach is to do this:

```
     typeof(x) == 'undefined'
```

See:  [JavaScript: undefined !== undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined)