# Difference in methods for testing undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never understood the difference in these two ways for testing the existence of an object...

```
typeof obj == "undefined"
```

vs.

```
obj == undefined
```

Is one preferred? I'm almost always using jQuery, is the second a jQuery only feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use typeof in Javascript type equality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481802/should-i-use-typeof-in-javascript-type-equality) and maybe [variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === “undefined”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined)

Comment: "is it a jQuery feature". Seriously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with

```
obj === undefined
```

is that if the `'obj'` identifier name doesn't exist in the (lexical) environment (or any of the outer environments), **an error is thrown** (which in turn breaks your program).

Btw names are bound to the environment by either declaring a variable (`var x;`), or assigning properties to the `window` object (`window.x = ...;`).

On the other hand

```
typeof obj === 'undefined'
```

doesn't throw (an error), and is therefore the preferred method.

---

Note though that you can't check for object existence in JavaScript. JavaScript code doesn't deal with objects directly, but trough references. If a given reference doesn't point to an object that doesn't mean that the object doesn't exist (it may be referenced by a different reference). What you can do is check whether or not a reference (like `obj` in your case) points to an Object value (or whether or not such an identifier name exists in the first place).

So if

```
typeof obj === 'undefined'
```

evaluates to `true`, that can mean:

- The name `'obj'` doesn't exist in the lexical environment or any outer environments,
- The name `'obj'` exists in the lexical environment chain (it's somewhere in it) and it's bound to the `undefined` value.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! In response to your first bit, what about prototype functions. For instance the method history.setState(), it seems to work testing history.setState == undefined, but I can't image the setState method is in the lexical environment if it's not supported.

Comment: @CambridgeMike My answer was about variables. With properties it's different (simpler). You can safely write `if ( obj.prop === undefined )`, although I still prefer `if ( typeof obj.prop === 'undefined' )`, just for consistency's sake. However, if the property in question is a method (which is implemented in some browsers and not implemented in some other browsers), you can even write `if ( !history.setState )` - that is how I would do it for methods. You can see this pattern in practice all over the [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js).

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` can be overwritten by an arbitrary value. When comparing using `==`, `null` will also return true, if `undefined` is `undefined`.

`typeof obj == "undefined"` is a safe way to test whether an object is undefined.

The following statements are equivalent:

```
var obj;
typeof obj == "undefined"; // Safe
obj === undefined;         // Provided that undefined has not been overwritten
obj === void 0;            // Void returns an `undefined` value. Also safe
```

The following comparisons don't produce the desired result:

```
var obj = null;
obj == undefined;          // True
var undefined = null;      // Overwriting undefined
obj === undefined;         // true
```

About [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js): The self-invoking function accepts two formal parameters, while only one is given. As a result, the second parameter effectively holds the `undefined` value. Now, the second parameter is also called `undefined`, so inside the function, the following is true: `typeof undefined == "undefined"` .

```
(function(window, undefined){
...
})(window)
```

Comment: You forgot to mention how you can just use `obj === undefined` because any environment where `undefined` is overwritten is not an environment where your code runs or where you care about the fact your code is broken.

Comment: @Raynos What's at the third line of my first block? If you were implying that one should not bother to not use `obj === undefined`, because it should not be overwritten: Frameworks should always take it into account.

Comment: I personally say a framework should only run in a sensible environment. That's like saying if someone does `delete Object.prototype.toString` and `delete Object.prototype.valueOf` I should gaurd against that. (As an aside, right a framework where the unit tests pass without `toString` and `valueOf`, I doubt it can be done)