# Test if something is not undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm checking `if(response[0].title !== undefined)`, but I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

Comment: See the answer here in stackoverflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: undefined !== undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined)

Answer (score 344, accepted):

`response[0]` is not defined, check if it is defined and then check for its property title.

```
if(typeof response[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof response[0].title !== 'undefined'){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Despite the number of votes, this is not a good way to perform the check because `undefined` is not a JavaScript keyword (although everyone seems to think it is). If you want to, you could create a variable called `undefined` and then this check will be incorrect. The only correct way is to check `(typeof myVar !== 'undefined')`.

Comment: @BadHorsie makes sense, I updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: What if a variable exists and contains the string that reads 'undefined'?

Comment: @BadHorsie Your argument is bogus. Why should I redefine `undefined`?

Comment: @amosrivera No, his/her comment did not make sense. You worsened your answer.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Hi Robert. I think it did although he/she is referring to old browser behavior. You can read more about it here: https://www.codereadability.com/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/

Comment: @amosrivera My point is: if you actually want to check for undefined do `thing === undefined`. No `typeof`, no `void`.—And I’m convinced that my point was even true with “old browser behavior”, i.e. from the beginning of Javascript. Even the website you mention supports my argument in the first paragraphs, and then it delves  into details about what it doesn’t recommend.

Answer (score 40):

Just check if `response[0]` is undefined:

```
if(response[0] !== undefined) { ... }
```

If you still need to explicitly check the title, do so after the initial check:

```
if(response[0] !== undefined && response[0].title !== undefined){ ... }
```

Answer (score 35):

I had trouble with all of the other code examples above. In Chrome, this was the condition that worked for me:

```
typeof possiblyUndefinedVariable !== "undefined"
```

I will have to test that in other browsers and see how things go I suppose.

Comment: Same - I found `undefined` had to be a string.

Comment: this must be something new with chrome (i'm on win chrome 41 atm). the accepted answer used to work just fine! :P

Answer (score 13):

Actually you must surround it with an Try/Catch block so your code won't stop from working.
Like this:

```
try{
    if(typeof response[0].title !== 'undefined') {
        doSomething();
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.log('responde[0].title is undefined'); 
  }
```

Comment: I was looking at IE 8 and needed to do a try catch.

Comment: this is the best way if you are testing if a function is undefined

Comment: throwing an error to check undefined is not a good solution. @amosrivera is the best solution.

Comment: @user3658423 : It isn't throwing an error. It only prevents the script from stopping if response is undeclared (because that would throw an error).

Comment: Sometimes errors can be helpful. With your proposed solution, if doSomething() throws an exception, all you would see in your console is "responde[0].title is undefined", instead of a useful message about an "un-caught exception @ line 123 of file xyz.js". Eventually a second developer will probably comment out the console.log() statement, making it more difficult for a 3rd developer to come in and fix a bug happening deep within doSomething().

Comment: Yes @Eric you're completely right. However my snippet does not intended to go beyond answering OP's question, which is about checking whether 'something' isn't undefined. In other words, following steps would be to treat, accordingly, whatever error comes inside catch block.

Answer (score 9):

typeof:

```
var foo;
if (typeof foo == "undefined"){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be because `response[0]` itself is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `condition == null`; 
It will resolve the problem

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're `response[0]` actually exists, the error seems to suggest it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You must first check whether `response[0]` is undefined, and only if it's not, check for the rest. That means that in your case, `response[0]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I know i went here 7 months late, but I found this questions and it looks interesting. I tried this on my browser console.

```
try{x,true}catch(e){false}
```

If variable x is undefined, error is catched and it will be false, if not, it will return true. So you can use eval function to set the value to a variable

```
var isxdefined = eval('try{x,true}catch(e){false}')
```

Comment: An interesting approach if I might say so myself.

Answer (score 0):

In some of these answers there is a fundamental misunderstanding about how to use `typeof`.

**Incorrect**

```
if (typeof myVar === undefined) {
```

**Correct**

```
if (typeof myVar === 'undefined') {
```

The reason is that `typeof` returns a string. Therefore, you should be checking that it returned the string "undefined" rather than `undefined` (not enclosed in quotation marks), which is itself one of [JavaScript's primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values). The `typeof` operator will never return a value of type `undefined`.

---

**Addendum**

Your code might technically work if you use the incorrect comparison, but probably not for the reason you think. There is no preexisting `undefined` variable in JavaScript - it's not some sort of magic keyword you can compare things to. You can actually create a variable called `undefined` and give it any value you like.

```
let undefined = 42;
```

And here is an example of how you can use this to prove the first method is incorrect:

https://jsfiddle.net/p6zha5dm/