# Checking if object is an object literal

Tags: javascript

Going on from this question here: [Checking for undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423765/checking-for-undefined)

I wanted to know if an object was an `Array`, now I need to test to see if an Object is specifically an `Object` and not just a subclass of an `Object`

Because at the moment an `Array` would return true if checked to see if it is an instance of an `Object`. Are there any other types that would evaluate to true?

[image]

**EXTRA INFO**

I have found that if you call `toString` on an `Array` that has one string element it resolves to that string element and not `"[object Array]"` so you need to be careful of that. For example:

```
["str1", "str2"].toString() === "[object Array]"
```

but

```
["str1"].toString() === "str1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test like this:

```
if ({}.toString.call(obj) == '[object Object]') {
  // is object
}

if ({}.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]') {
  // is array
}
```

`obj` is any object. Same with objects such as `RegExp`, `Date`, etc... In old IE you may need to do `({})` for it to work properly.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/exofup/2/edit

Comment: `obj` is any object (object, array, date, regex...)

Comment: You're missing the point @SmartLemon. You need to pass the object in question as context. You're using the `toString` method of `{}`. It oculd be written as `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`.

Comment: Well then you would do that anyway... `({}).toString() == '[object Object]'` results to true and `([]).toString() == '[object Object]'` results to false

Comment: The `toString` method of any object will evaluate to `'[object Object]` if it is an object correct? While it would evaluate to something other then that if it wasn't

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Yeah if you're **just** testing for an object type Object I guess it should work. This was more of a general answer, but use it how you need it.

Comment: Sweet as. That is what I was getting through. I just want its type :P. So no need for `call(obj)` correct? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't complicate things, you can use the above technique to check ANY type of object in JavaScript, for example http://jsbin.com/exofup/2/edit