# Why doesn't !!!undefined work in JS golf?

Tags: javascript, recursion, undefined, stack-overflow

I'm currently golfing an integer digit reversal method just for fun (and it's recursive because recursion is cool). Here is the code that came out of [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/):

```
function rev(r,e){var n=r%10;return void 0==e?rev(r,0):0==r?e:n==r?10*e+r:rev((r-n)/10,10*e+n)}
```

Note that UglifyJS uses `void 0` as a synonym for `undefined`, which [is probably a better choice in everyday programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041123/test-if-something-is-undefined-in-javascript).

I stumbled across this test for `undefined`:

```
function isundef(x) {
  return !!!x;
}
```

Because the point of the `undefined` test is to cram a helper-method-style recursive algorithm into one function that can re-call itself with proper parameters, I simply tried replacing `void 0==e` with `isundef(e)`.

```
function rev(r,e){var n=r%10;return isundef(e)?rev(r,0):0==r?e:n==r?10*e+r:rev((r-n)/10,10*e+n)}
```

In Chrome latest, this doesn't work. I get a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. **Why doesn't `isundef` work for testing for `undefined` in this context?!!!**

Edit:

Why doesn't a [truthiness test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in?rq=1) work either?

```
function rev(r,e){var n=r%10;return e?0==r?e:n==r?10*e+r:rev((r-n)/10,10*e+n):rev(r,0)}
```

Comment: By the way, before you migrate or close as code golf, this question is actually about JS syntax, not golfing strategies.

Comment: Why not just use `return typeof e == 'undefined'` instead? If `e` truly is undefined, as in not declared, just testing `e` will give you an error!

Comment: @adeneo because this is code golf. I'm also just trying to be creative.

Comment: `!!!x` is true for all falsey values such as false, '', etc

Comment: If you're trying to make it short, surely `return !!!e ? ... ` would do that best ?

Comment: @megawac But if I substitue `!!!e` or even `e` for `void 0==e` or the normal way `e==undefined`, it just _doesn't work_.

Comment: @adeneo That was part of the question: if you run the code as such, it SOs.

Comment: It's not checking for undefined it's checking for falsey values. `!!!x !== x == void 0` in all cases. Just unwrap it to `!x`

Comment: Also, why `!!!e`? Why not simply `!e`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant okay, they're equivalent. But **the question** is why neither can substitute for `void 0==e`, etc. in my code. So I am being kind of X-Y here.

Comment: @SimonKuang Because `undefined == 0` is `false`, whereas `!undefined` is `true`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You lost me there. Could you explain that a bit further and post it as an answer?

Comment: @SimonKuang hm, sorry, what kind of explanation do you need? It's simply that your function does **not** test whether its argument is `undefined`. Rather, it tests whether it is **any** falsy value.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant oh! So does it SO because `r=0` the first time around? (it's meant to be called with one argument)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I think you should post that as an answer --- that when the function calls itself with `rev(r,0)`, `!!!0` makes it recurse infinitely.

Comment: @SimonKuang Exactly. Okay, will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your `isundef` function does not check its argument for `undefined`. For any falsy value `e`, the expression `!e` is `true`. This is the case for `e === undefined`, but also for all falsy values of `e`, for example `e === null`, `e === 0`, etc.

So when you call your function with `rev(arg, 0)`, then it will call itself recursively ad infinitum.