# asp:textbox Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I get this error so my update button doesnt work and I havent updated my database progress because of this error.I want to be visible of textbox and I try to do in .cs side

This javascript codes using checkboxs and textboxs send to cs side with json

```js
        function UpdateDetails1() {

            var bEnabled = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_Enabled_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bDisplayDetails = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_DisplayDetails_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var b3rdParty = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_b3rdParty_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bDisplayOpenNow = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_DisplayOpenNow_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bReservation = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_Reservation_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bPromotion = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_Promotion_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bOnlyPromotion = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_OnlyPromotion_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bAllowFollow = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_AllowFollow_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bAlacarte = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_Alacarte_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var bDisplayOpenEat = GetCheckBoxVal($("#<%=CB_DisplayOpenEat_Edit.ClientID%>"));
            var Coord_Lat = $("#<%=TB_Coord_Lat_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
            var Coord_Long = $("#<%=TB_Coord_Long_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
            var Price = $("#<%=TB_Price_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
            alert(Price);
            var Phone_Number = $('#<%=TB_Phone_Number_Edit.ClientID%>')[0].value;
            if (bReservation == true)
                $("#display_res_schedule").css("display", "block");
            else
                $("#display_res_schedule").css("display", "none");

            var jsonData = '{ bEnabled: "' + bEnabled + '",' +
                    'bDisplayDetails: "' + bDisplayDetails + '",' +
                    'b3rdParty:  "' + b3rdParty + '",' +
                    'Price:  "' + Price + '",' +
                    'bDisplayOpenNow: "' + bDisplayOpenNow + '",' +
                    'bReservation: "' + bReservation + '",' +
                    'bPromotion: "' + bPromotion + '",' +
                    'Phone_Number: "' + Phone_Number + '",' +
                    'bOnlyPromotion: "' + bOnlyPromotion + '",' +
                    'bAllowFollow: "' + bAllowFollow + '",' +
                    'bAlacarte: "' + bAlacarte + '",' +
                    'bDisplayOpenEat: "' + bDisplayOpenEat + '",' +
                    'Coord_Lat: "' + Coord_Lat + '",' +
                    'Coord_Long: "' + Coord_Long + '" }';
            
            alert(jsonData);
           // var jsonData = '{ bEnabled: "' + bEnabled + '",' +
           //       'bDisplayOpenNow: "' + bDisplayOpenNow + '",' +
           //         'bReservation: "' + bReservation + '",' +
           //         'Coord_Lat: "' + Coord_Lat + '",' +
           //         'Coord_Long: "' + Coord_Long + '" }';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Edit.aspx/UpdateDetails1",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: GetDetails1,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

I need to do visible false checkboxes and textboxes that I don't use.But TB_Phone_Number_Edit.Visible gets Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined error

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadType = Request.QueryString["t"].ToString();
        if (LoadType == "Agency")
        {
            CB_DisplayOpenNow.Visible = false;
            CB_DisplayOpenNow_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_Alacarte.Visible = false;
            CB_Alacarte_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_DisplayOpenEat.Visible = false;
            CB_DisplayOpenEat_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_Reservation.Visible = false;
            CB_Reservation_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_Promotion.Visible = false;
            CB_Promotion_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_OnlyPromotion.Visible = false;
            CB_OnlyPromotion_Edit.Visible = false;
            TB_Price_Edit.Visible = false;
            DDL_Currency.Visible = false;
            DDL_Camera.Visible = false;
            CB_AllowFollow.Visible = false;
            CB_AllowFollow_Edit.Visible = false;
            WhatDoNow.Visible = false;
            Alacarte.Visible = false;
            WhatEatNow.Visible = false;
            Promotion.Visible = false;
            Reservation.Visible = false;
            OnlyPromotion.Visible = false;
            Price.Visible = false;
            Camera.Visible = false;
            AllowFollow.Visible = false;
            Label23.Visible = false;
            Label24.Visible = false;
            Label25.Visible = false;
            Label26.Visible = false;
            Label27.Visible = false;
            Label29.Visible = false;
            Label30.Visible = false;
            Label33.Visible = false;
            Label34.Visible = false;
            TB_Price_Edit.Visible = false;
        }
        else if(LoadType == "Tour"){
            CB_b3rdParty.Visible = false;
            CB_b3rdParty_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_Alacarte.Visible = false;
            CB_Alacarte_Edit.Visible = false;
            DDL_Camera.Visible = false;
            CB_AllowFollow.Visible = false;
            CB_AllowFollow_Edit.Visible = false;
            CB_DisplayOpenEat.Visible = false;
            CB_DisplayOpenEat_Edit.Visible = false;
            b3rdParty.Visible = false;
            Alacarte.Visible = false;
            WhatEatNow.Visible = false;
            Camera.Visible = false;
            AllowFollow.Visible = false;
            Label18.Visible = false;
            Label24.Visible = false;
            Label25.Visible = false;
            Label33.Visible = false;
            Label34.Visible = false;
            Phone_Number.Visible = false;
            TB_Phone_Number_Edit.Visible = false;
            Label8.Enabled = false;

        }
```

Comment: I change codes as in this article but this mistake has continued.How I fix this mistake.Can I help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the problem is not in `GetCheckBoxVal` any of the following statements is causing your issue:

```
var Coord_Lat = $("#<%=TB_Coord_Lat_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
var Coord_Long = $("#<%=TB_Coord_Long_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
var Price = $("#<%=TB_Price_Edit.ClientID%>")[0].value;
var Phone_Number = $('#<%=TB_Phone_Number_Edit.ClientID%>')[0].value;
```

Why? Because if the css selector given to jQuery returns no matches, the array will have zero elements, aka, its length will be 0. That does mean that even on element[0] there is nothing, its value is undefined. Trying to get a property or invoke a method on an undefined value gives you the exception you see.

As the suggested [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041123/test-if-something-is-not-undefined-in-javascript) suggest you should guard against this situation. One possible way is to introduce a utility function:

```
// this gets the value property of an object and if object is undefined
// returns a default
function getValueOrDefault(someObject, reasonableDefault) {

    return someObject === undefined ? reasonableDefault : someObject.value;
}

// your original function
function UpdateDetails1() { 
    // rest of your code
}
```

With that function in place your code becomes:

```
var Coord_Lat = getValueOrDefault($("#<%=TB_Coord_Lat_Edit.ClientID%>")[0], '0.0');
var Coord_Long = getValueOrDefault($("#<%=TB_Coord_Long_Edit.ClientID%>")[0], '0.0');
var Price = getValueOrDefault($("#<%=TB_Price_Edit.ClientID%>")[0],0);
var Phone_Number = getValueOrDefault($('#<%=TB_Phone_Number_Edit.ClientID%>')[0],'+1 010');
```

That should resolve the Uncaught type error. It is up to you to come up with reasonable defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a textbox to `Visible = false` makes it not render in your html. So when you try to get the value in your javascript, it effectively does not exist, making it `undefined`.

To fix this, either replace the textbox by a hidden field or change the opacity so that the textbox is there but transparent.

Comment: I know textbox being visible false isn't rendered in my html.But how I fix this mistake?