# What is the best way to compare a value against 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript

Is there any differences between

```
var a;
(a == undefined)
(a === undefined)
((typeof a) == "undefined")
((typeof a) === "undefined")
```

Which one should we use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703102/469210 seems relevant to this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: undefined !== undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ironically, `undefined` can be redefined in JavaScript, not that anyone in their right mind would do that, for example:

```
undefined = "LOL!";
```

at which point all future equality checks against `undefined` will yeild unexpected results!

As for the difference between `==` and `===` (the equality operators), == will attempt to coerce values from one type to another, in English that means that `0 == "0"` will evaluate to true even though the types differ (Number vs String) - developers tend to avoid this type of loose equality as it can lead to difficult to debug errors in your code.

As a result it's safest to use:

```
"undefined" === typeof a
```

When checking for undefinedness :)

Comment: ({tries undefined = true}) Who in their... why on... AAHG! WHY WOULD SOMEONE? That is a true failure of EcmaScript. I had never even thought to do that.

Comment: As per my example, 'for teh lolz!' The next iteration of EcmaScript (codenamed Harmony) will include support for constants, which can only be a good thing for our sanity ;)  http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aconst

Comment: it is link to the first part of your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null/2703131#2703131

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use

```
[undefined, null].indexOf(variable) > -1
```

to check also for null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a;
(a == undefined) //true
(a === undefined) //true
((typeof a) == "undefined") //true
((typeof a) === "undefined") //true
```

BUT:

```
var a;
(a == "undefined") //false
(a === "undefined") //false
((typeof a) == undefined) //false
((typeof a) === undefined) //false
```

Comment: @JohnJohn well if they all yield the same thing there is no `difference`. But i believe the best bet is your 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mentioned above:

```
"undefined" === typeof a
```

But if you have lots of variables to check, your code can get ugly at some point, so you may consider to use Java's approach:

```
try { vvv=xxx; zzz=yyyy; mmm=nnn; ooo=ppp; } 
catch(err){ alert(err.message); }
```

Obviously alert() shouldn't be used in a production version, but in debugging version it's very useful. 
It should work even in old browsers like IE 6:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4yahc5d8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If a is undefined, then

```
a == undefined
```

will actually throw an error. Use

```
(typeof a) === "undefined"
```

Instead.

Comment: Gah, you're right, I missed the "var a" at the beginning of OP's code.

Answer (score -2):

If you declare `var a`, then it won't be undefined any more - it will be `null` instead.  I usually use `typeof a == undefined` - and it works fine.  This is especially useful in this situation:

```
function myfunc(myvar)
{
    if(typeof myvar == "undefined")
    {
        //the function was called without an argument, simply as myfunc()
    }
}
```

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) returns a string.

Comment: That if statement will be `FALSE` --  `typeof` returns a string value.

Comment: Well, I used it just today in a production system - and it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Aleks that is bc you are **not** using a `===` to determine equality.