# undefined variable in jquery code

Tags: jquery

I asked a question about the undefined value in javascript a few days ago. ([What is the best way to compare a value against 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108109/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-a-value-against-undefined))
I conclude that it is a bad practice to do `!== undefined` as `undefined` can be set to 'another' value.

```
undefined='foo';
var b;
(b !== undefined) // true
```

I gave a quick look at the jquery code, I realized that in every part, the author use `!== undefined` and not `typeof var !== "undefined"`

```
// Setting one attribute
if ( value !== undefined ) {
// Optionally, function values get executed if exec is true
    exec = !pass && exec && jQuery.isFunction(value);
```

Is it a possible mistake? Even if I know that we should be crazy to reassign the value of undefined - for the most popular library I think it can cause some mistakes...

Who is in the right way?

Comment: *"I conclude that it is a bad practice to do `!== undefined` as `undefined` can be set..."* No, the bad practice is to set `undefined` to another value, and then to write code that accommodates that bad practice.

Comment: @patrick if you have a safer way to check if a variable is not defined, why not using it?

Comment: Because I do not believe in writing cryptic code only to accommodate bad coding practices. The appropriate solution is to remove the offending code. Comparing to `undefined` is just fine, though I can see the benefit in creating a local `undefined` so that you don't need to traverse to the global every time you want to access it. To create a local `undefined`, I'd rather use `void`, which always returns `undefined`. `var undef = void 0;` But I'd only do that for performance purposes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`undefined` in the jQuery code is actually an undefined parameter of a function wrapping the whole code:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    // jQuery code here
    // undefined is the undefined parameter
}(window)); // notice we don't pass a second argument here
```

That's perfectly safe, as the `undefined` parameter is local to the function, and nobody except the code in this function can assign to it.

Using a more clear syntax:

```
var myFunc = function(window, undefined) {
    // jQuery code here

    // The undefined variable is the undefined parameter

    // If the function has been called without a second argument,
    // then the undefined parameter is undefined.
};
myFunc(window); // no second argument
```

Comment: I am curions, if I set `undefined = 'foo'` before including jquery, does that mean `'foo'` gets passed in to the second parameter?

Comment: no, the function would still be called without a second argument, so the value of this argument is *undefined*

Comment: oh nice I didn't notice that second parameter not being there. Thanks for clearing up.

Comment: @Amir: `var a = 5; function test(a){alert("hello");}; test();` See how the parameter wouldn't be 5?

Comment: @Stefan, I just didn't see the method call earlier. But thanks for providing an example.

Comment: Thanks, any idea where it can ge useful to set a value to undefined ( = 'foo')? why javascript allow us to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you reassign `undefined` to something else and you expect to use a large library, then you get what you deserve as far as I'm concerned.  It's perfectly OK to test if a variable is `undefined` and jQuery needs to do that in many cases to tell which optional parameters are or aren't passed to various functions.