# Javascript undefined condition

Tags: javascript

Could somebody explain to me the difference between `if(obj.x == undefined)` and `if(typeof obj.x == 'undefined')`

In some context the first one works fine, but in other I need to use the second way.

Questions

1 - What is the difference between the two condition?

2 - Is there a best practice?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined

Comment: Often it's good enough to just check the _truthiness_ of the value: `if (obj.x)`.

Comment: `undefined` is a variable, not a constant, and can be assigned a value. Because of this, one school of thought says the second path is safer, since you cannot be sure of the value of `undefined`.  There is another school of thought that says those who redefine undefined deserve exactly what they get.

Comment: If you want to know if a property exists on an object, do this `if ( 'x' in obj )` or this `if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( 'x' ) )`. (Use the second one, if you don't want to look up the prototype chain.

Comment: @Chris Nielson - as of 1.8.5 `undefined` is non-writable

Comment: @David Note that one can explicitly assign the `undefined` value to a property. Therefore, when a property returns the value `undefined` it can mean two things: (1) the object doesn't have such a property, (2) the object does have such a property and it's values is `undefined`. So, if you need to check whether or not a property exists in an object, don't compare it to `undefined`, but instead use one of the two methods I provided in my comment above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best practice is to not just check the *truthiness* but the **strict equality**

example

```
if (obj.x === undefined) {}
```

this use to be an issue because `undefined` (a global property) use to be writable, as of 1.8.5 is is non-writable, providing you with a secure comparison in ES5 spec environments.

per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: A secure comparison? In which environment? Afaik, you can assign to the `undefined` variable in all modern browsers...

Comment: It's still not reliable. Even in ES5, `undefined` can be used as a variable name within a function: `(function() { var undefined = "foo"; alert(undefined); })()`

Comment: Then why would the MDN choose this as the primary example of how to see if a variable is `undefined`?

Comment: @Šime: @jondavidjohn is right about the global `undefined` property being read-only in current browsers.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: MDN is not infallible.

Comment: @Tim It doesn't appear to be read-only: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYuq/1/ (tested in Chrome, Opera and IE8)

Comment: I'm not asserting they are, I'm simply trusting the architect of the language to not propagate bad practices of their own product.

Comment: MDN is not written by Brendan Eich. It's also publicly editable. More to the point, unquestioningly trusting any resource other than the language's spec is a mistake. @Šime: I've responded about browser specifics in the comments to my answer.

Comment: @jon You say in your answer that `x === undefined` is a secure comparison, but it isn't. You can still write to `undefined` in Chrome and Opera, so as for now `x === undefined` is **not** secure, ergo, it's a potential security threat (as tiny as it is, it still is one).

Answer (score 1):

The two would usually be equivalent if you replaced the equality operator `==` with the strict equality operator `===`. So `obj.x === undefined` and `typeof obj.x == "undefined"` are usually equivalent.

However, in pre-ECMAScript 5 environments (which still acount for the majority of web requests, in general), `undefined` is a writable property of the global object, meaning that `undefined` may be used as variable name or the global property may be assigned a different value. ECMAScript 5 makes the global property read-only, but even then, `undefined` may still be used as variable name within a function, meaning that the `typeof` check is always safer.

One further point in favour of `typeof` is that it may be used to check for a variable that may not have been declared whereas a direct comparison will throw a `ReferenceError` if the variable has not been declared. For example:

```
typeof foo == "undefined" // true
foo === undefined // ReferenceError
```

However, this is an unusual and not generally helpful thing to be doing.

Comment: In what browsers is `undefined` (the global variable) not writable?

Comment: @Šime: Try it. I've tried it on my machine in Firefox 6, Chrome 13, Safari 5.1 and Opera 11.50. Safari and Firefox do not allow assignment to the `undefined` global object property, Chrome and Opera do. However, that's not very relevant: the point is that a compliant ES5 environment will not allow it, and such environments do exist.

Comment: And I just happened to only have Chrome and Opera on my machine `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent tests because of the quite convoluted handling of special values by javascript. In the specific

```
undefined == null
```

is true, but `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"` while `typeof null` is `"object"`.

The rules for those special values are quite complex and IMO illogical, so I think there's no "general rule". What you may find are common forms, for example

```
var value = obj.x || default_value;
```

that can be used if you're sure that obj will never be `undefined` or `null` (because in that case an exception would be thrown) and assuming that `0`, `NaN` or an empty string should be considered as if no value was provided (because they're all "logically false" values). An empty array or an empty javascript object instead are considered "logically true".

Why is it that way? Why does `(null).x` throw an exception when `null` according to `typeof` is apparently an object and searching for a non-existent field in an object normally returns `undefined` instead?

I've no idea.

I never tried to find a logic in all those strange rules. I'm not actually even 100% sure there's one.

My suggestion is just to study and experiment with them.

Comment: If you're unsure of why this admittedly unintuitive behaviour happens, check the ECMAScript specification. Your observations follow directly from well-defined rules you'll find there.

Comment: @Tim Down: I've actually tried to check the specs but I personally found that document close to impossible to read. I prefer experimenting with those side cases because anyway it wouldn't be that helpful writing programs that in theory should run but that in practice don't (unless you target is not writing software that runs but just being able to find someone to blame instead).

Answer (score 0):

second is easier and faster than first. First requires additional setup, definition of undefined and check wheter obj contains x as a property or method. second makes the check whether obj.x has been whenever defined and assigned

PS.: undefined will be evaluated to null so 
obj.x == undefined is equivalent to obj.x == null

Answer (score 0):

the best way to test for conditionality isusing `obj.x` this checks for both null-ability and undefined .

Thus

```
if(!obj.x) 
{
  alert(obj.x);
}
else   
{
  alert("obj.x is null or undefined");  //obj.x is null or undefined or any false value which is what you want. like obj.x is false or 0
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. The else-branch will be executed if `obj.x` is any falsy value, not just null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference of these two condition is typeof

The **typeof** operator is used to get the data type (returns a string) of its operand. The operand can be either a literal or a data structure such as a variable, a function, or an object. The operator returns the data type.

```
if (typeof obj.x === 'undefined') {
    txt = "x is undefined";
  } else {
    txt = "x is defined";
  }
```