# Wooslider: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

The Wooslider plugin on my Wordpress site suddenly stopped loading images on all pages it's used on. Can somebody look into this and tell me what the issue is and how to fix it?

The error code I receive in the console is:

```html
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):296
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please include jquery library link before you've added woo slider library.

Add this script to header.php in your wp theme

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there, it worked! Thank you! How could it have happened suddenly that the jquery library was missing as it was working fine before with no changes?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all lines which link `JQuery` to your page and add below the line, which is fo latest version of 'JQuery`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

in your code before `</head>` 
Something like

```
<head> 
  ....
  ....

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

What this will do is load `JQuery` code before loading the contents of  `<body> ... </body>` code.

Adding some links related to above problem

1. [Handling code which relies on jQuery before jQuery is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298430/handling-code-which-relies-on-jquery-before-jquery-is-loaded)
2. [Best Practice: Where to include your  tags](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/best-practice-where-to-include-your-script-tags)

Comment: Hi there, really appreciate your thorough explanation but adding the script the user provided below worked for me, but your solution doesn't seem to work!

Comment: That's not a problem, I was just trying to help.

Comment: Appreciate the links you added too