# Javascript undefined, empty strings, and if statements

Tags: javascript

I am not some one who has done alot in javascript. My background is in Java/C++. I am currently working on a project that is using alot of javascript however and I came across something that doesn't make sense to me but hopefully some javascript guru out there can give me a nice logical explanation.

```
var noDefinition = undefined;
var emptyString = "";
var noDefinitionAndEmptyString = noDefinition + emptyString;

console.log("NoDefinition");
console.log(noDefinition);

console.log("EmptyString");
console.log(emptyString);

console.log("noDefinition+emptyString");
console.log(noDefinitionAndEmptyString);

console.log("************************");
if(noDefinition == undefined)
{
    console.log("No Definition is undefined");
}


if(emptyString == undefined)
{
    console.log("emptyString is undefined");
}

if(noDefinitionAndEmptyString == undefined)
{
    console.log("noDefiniton and emptyString is undefined");
}
```

The code above produces the following results in my console:
 [INFO] NoDefinition 
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] EmptyString 
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] noDefinition+emptyString
 [INFO] undefined
 [INFO] ************************
 [INFO] No Definition is undefined

So as you can see when I output the variables noDefinition and emptyString to the console, it produces blank output. When I concatenate them the console will produce undefined. However if I then proceed to use an if statement and compare each of them to undefined. The only if that executes is the first one.

This occurs even though when put to a console the value just shows up blank. Also     the concatenation which shows up as undefined in the console fails its compare against undefined and never executes.  I am confused by this and I am hoping out there some one can give me an explanation about what is going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: undefined !== undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate undefined with a string it becomes a string

```
var foo = undefined;
var bar = "";
console.log(foo+bar, typeof(foo+bar));
* output *
undefined string
```

ECMAScript Docs - http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php
Not sure but reading the doc on Page 141 you can find this

> 15.5.1 The String Constructor Called as a Function
>
> When String is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type
>   conversion.

Which lets me to believe why concatenation of anything with a string outputs a string

Answer (score 2):

1. `console.log` doesn't print anything when it receives a `undefined` value (implementation-specific).
2. When you concatenate `undefined` with an empty string, the resulting value is `"undefined"`. That's printed.

The previous bullet points explain your observations.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting your example might shed more light on what actually happens when concatenating a string and an undefined value:

```
var noDefinition = undefined;
var emptyString = "";
var noDefinitionAndEmptyString = noDefinition + emptyString;
console.log("************************");
console.log("NoDefinition:" + " " + noDefinition + " " + typeof(noDefinition));

console.log("EmptyString:"+ " " + emptyString + " " + typeof(emptyString));

console.log("noDefinition+emptyString: " + noDefinitionAndEmptyString + " " + typeof(noDefinitionAndEmptyString));

console.log("************************");
```

Results in:

```
************************
NoDefinition: undefined undefined
EmptyString: string
noDefinition+emptyString: undefined string
************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
if (typeof noDefinition == "undefined") ...
```

Comment: THis is better approach: if (typeof noDefinition === "undefined")

Answer (score 0):

`noDefinitionAndEmptyString` is actually a `string` (you can use `console.info(typeof noDefinitionAndEmptyString)`) and its value is 'undefined'. This happens because of the concatenation - an implicit cast to `string` occurs, and undefined variable, casted to string, is the string 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

`if(noDefinition == null)` covers typeOf 'undefined' and typeOf 'null', but you may want to add an and statement to make sure it's just not an empty string... like so:

`if(noDefinitionAndEmptyString == null || noDefinitionAndEmptyString == "")`