# Having trouble with undefined !== undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, types

I'm trying to process a complete function in an ajax call. If the value is undefined, I want cast a var as an empty string. Otherwise, I would like to capture the value into a string array.

The problem is I'm entering the if statement, even when logging the value of the variable in question returns as undefined. What am I missing here?

```
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        if(typeof $(this).attr("ows_Products") !== undefined) {
          console.log($(this).attr("ows_Products"));
          arr = $(this).attr("ows_Products").split(',');
        }
        else {
          arr = "";
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined

Comment: @web_bod that looked to be more in terms of comparing == to ===, meaning null == undefined = true, whereas null === undefined = false

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`typeof` returns a string value, so you'll need to compare with `"undefined"` as a string.  E.g.,

```
if(typeof $(this).attr("ows_Products") !== "undefined") { ... }
```

---

Edit - more info:

If you check out the [MDN page for typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), you'll see this:

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

This is very different from returning the `Type` itself (which in JavaScript would probably be something like returning a constructor function like `String`, `Array`, etc.). Therefore, when using `typeof`, you'll always be comparing to strings like `"object"`, `"string"`, `"undefined"`, etc.

Comment: Ahh yes. It's the little things, sometimes.

Comment: The simplicity of the solution is generally inversely proportionate to how long you spent staring at the problem :)

Comment: Ha, thanks. I honestly have to give my dad (also a programmer with far more years of experience) credit for that statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).attr("own_Products")){
       arr = $(this).attr("ows_Products").split(',');
}else{
       arr=""
}
```