# Why does jQuery file have two parameters in its function but receives only one parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

I am trying to learn about js scopes and anonymous functions. I have tried to read the jQuery.js file and it looks like this:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

...

}(window));
```

Why does it have in the function params `undefined` when no parameter is being passed to it when it is executed?

Comment: It is already explained in here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Comment: Read ScottLahteine's comment in response to the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined). It's to ensure that, within the method, the variable called `undefined` is genuinely undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method is used so you can be sure that no one has previously redefined `undefined` value with something like

```
var undefined = true;
```

or with other tricky/evil assignments outside the jQuery scoped function. So, inside that function every comparison done against `undefined` is safe.