# Javascript catchup undefined

Tags: javascript

I have build an array loader with javascript.

[Here the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayQH2/)

When I directly click last, I get undefined. I tryed to catch it up with something like this

```
var lastWord = (function() {

            return function() {
            var resultWord = wordArray[--count % wordArray.length];
                if (typeof resultWord == "undefined")
                { 
                return false;
                }
                else 
                {
                return wordArray[--count % wordArray.length];
                }
            }
        }

}());
```

But didn't worked, any suggestions?

Comment: Why is everyone having anonymous functions return anonymous functions these days. So crazy!

Comment: @thatidiotguy http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: But I don't see that outer function adding any value here.  There are no parameters to the function and no local variables that the returned function closes over.  It's just syntactic noise with no benefit.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I agree. This seems like an overzealous professor going wild with power.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467539/javascript-modulo-not-behaving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/ayQH2/2/

The problem is that the sign returned by the modulus operator is the sign of its first operand.  So, for example

```
(-17) % 12 // == -5 , not 7
```

This will probably work, and does not include the extra function wrappers:

```
var nextWord = function() {
    // silly work-around for negative modulus issue
    var index = (++count % wordArray.length) + wordArray.length
    return wordArray[index % wordArray.length];
};
var lastWord = function() {
    // silly work-around for negative modulus issue
    var index = (--count % wordArray.length) + wordArray.length
    return wordArray[index % wordArray.length];
};
```

There are plenty of other ways to deal with this.  Perhaps a better one would be to ensure that `count` never escapes the proper range, doing something like

```
count = (count == wordArray.length - 1) ? 0 : count++; // increment
count = (count == 0) ? wordArray.length - 1 : count--; // decrement
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is undefined for the first time is because there is nothing in wordArray at negative indeces. There is no "last" word before you have hit update. Does that make sense? It works fine after you have hit update once.

Comment: yeah I know that, but I want to catch it up, so nothing happens if the value is undefined

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined

Comment: as you can see above I alredy tried `if (typeof VARIABLE == "undefined")`

Comment: @Johnny187 Why is not in the fiddle then? You can't post different code in different places. Make a new one with the current code, and I will gladly look at it again.