# 'undefined' variable works as key to object with 'undefined' property name

Tags: javascript

Consider the following...

```
var x = {};
x.undefined = "Hello World!";
var y;

//Prints "Hello World!"
console.log(x[y]);
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TuWfK/)

Why does this happen? Is it because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776950/javascript-undefined-undefined), where it is returning a string instead of the actual undefined?

Comment: The same trick works with x.true = "Hello World".. x.true and x['true'] are refer to the same value.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you do `x.undefined` you are setting a property of `x` called `'undefined'`.  The fact that it shares a name with `undefined` (a <strike>reserved word</strike> variable with `writable:false`) is coincidence.

Later on when you do, `console.log(x[y])`, you are looking for `y` in `x`.  Keys of objects are strings, so `y` is converted to a string.  When `undefined` is converted to a string, it becomes `'undefined'`.  That's why `'Hello World!'` is returned.

Comment: So when passing it as a key to `x`, JavaScript is automatically parsing the value of `y` which is `undefined` to a string literal "undefined"?

Comment: @JakeMorrison: Yep, exactly.  It's converting `y` to a string :-)

Comment: `undefined` is not a reserved word in any way. It is [a normal global variable, with `writable: false`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3)

Comment: @Esailija: Didn't realize it was defined that way.  Thanks :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat `void 0 > http://jsfiddle.net/g5759/`.. just spreading the awareness :P

Answer (score 8):

When properties are accessed using `.` notation, the property name is not evaluated as an expression, it's a literal string.

```
x.undefined
```

is equivalent to:

```
x['undefined']
```

To set a property whose key is `undefined`, you would have to write:

```
x[undefined] = "Bye, cruel world";
```

Interestingly, Chrome lets me do this.

Comment: In that last case, the key `undefined` is coerced to `"undefined"`, because [ECMAScript property access](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) (see step 6) coerces the key to a string with [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8), and `ToString(undefined) => "undefined"`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out by calling `typeof` the key.

Comment: @apsillers curious, is it just chrome that allows undefined or do all modern browsers conform to that spec

Comment: @Melbourne2991 All JavaScript implementations should follow the ECMAScript specification. If a JavaScript engine doesn't follow the spec, it's not really JavaScript. (Of course, an implementation may be incomplete or have bugs in it, but spec conformance is the goal.)

Comment: @apsillers's comment should be marked as the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

You define the "undefined" property for x, but you don't override the "undefined" property of global object